# What is this ground cover?

Tags: identification

I'm growing this in England, a cutting from a garden in Scotland. It's about 10--15cm high, and looks like it spreads by runners. Any idea what it is and how I should look after it?
[image: green pointed leaves, orange-brown dead leaves, ground cover with runners]
I love the orange-brown of the dead leaves, which persist and make a nice backdrop for the green.

Edit: it flowered, with pink fluffy spikes, and I'm guessing Persicaria vacciniifolia.
[image]

Comment: Does it disappear below ground in winter? Ever seen any flowers on it?

Comment: Periwinkle? But I never seen such orange leaves, and it should have opposite leaves, and longer runners.

Comment: @Bamboo It doesn't disappear below ground -- it stayed pretty much like this all winter. (But in the east of England we only rarely get below freezing.) I've not seen any flowers, since I planted it in autumn last year.

Comment: So why are there all the dead leaves, any idea? I assumed they were fallen when it died back during winter, are some still attached to the plant? I don't recognise this at all I'm afraid. Its not one of the periwinkles... Perhaps posting another image later as it develops and grows might make for easier ID